# Using ssionId and URL Parameters without concatenating them

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jsessionid

I have a url like this:

"http://mydomain.com/aservlet/?id=auniqueId;jsessionid=ABCDEFGHIJK"

Now in my servlet when i retrieve the parameter with:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
```

the id parameter will be `auniqueId;jsessionid=ABCDEFGHIJK`

what i want is `auniqueId`

The problem is, that i don't know which parameter will be the last so i would have to parse all parameters for ";" sign first and remove it before i can use them.

Is this really necessary or is there a more clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

I m assuming you have gone all this steps or if you used other impl and import * also , please try this one.

Ok .. you need it like this "http://mydomain.com/aservlet/jsessionid=ABCDEFGHIJK&&id=uniqueid"

you need to have `HttpServletRequest req` on your servlet action as parameter .

```
Then 

try
{
    HttpSession ssn = req.getSession(); //try to handle servle exceptions too
    String ssnId = ssn.getId();
    System.out.println(ssnId); //check for null first on your real code 

}
catch(Exception ex){
 System.out.println("Exception "+ex.getMessage());
}

OutPUt: ABCDEFGHKLL; //only the id part not the jsession string
```

Comment: The problem is not about getting the sessionId. It's about not having the session id mixed in with the url parameters like "anuniqueId" in this case.

Comment: @Chris...you confused me the above will return you just un mixed ID like ='ABACDEFHJS'...i thouhg that was what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry the question was a bit confusing. I edited it to make it more clear. But i think i already found the solution. Query parameters has to come AFTER the path parameters not before them.

Comment: okay you were asking on how to pass the id with the session id